# Why does scalar-value function fail with null parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

In TSQL, I need to do a cross-reference from our value for a given field, to the specified client's value. We have many clients and each client's encoding of values is different. The db is a CRM Dynamics 2011 db.

I set up a scalar-valued function like this:

```
 [dbo].[fn_GetXRef] 
(@Guid uniqueidentifier, @LookupType nvarchar(20), 
 @OurValue nvarchar(20), @Parm4 nvarchar(20) = null,
 @Parm5 uniqueidentifier = null, @Parm6 nvarchar(1) = null,
 @Parm7 nvarchar(1) = null)
```

Parms 4, 5, 6 and 7 may be null; they are used for some cross-references but not others.

If I run execute the logic outside the function, it works. When I execute the function it returns NULL.

For example:

```
Select dbo.fn_getXRef('22BF20B1-55F1-E211-BF73-00155D062F00',
                            'Lookup Type 1', 'Our value', null,  null, null, '3')
```

It returns null but pulling the logic out of the function and running it as a separate query, and using the same input parameter values, returns the correct client-value.

What am I not seeing?

---

update: 12/11/13

Thanks all for trying to help. While researching I found some nifty code that looked more efficient than my own so I re-wrote the function using that technique and now it works. It uses OPTION (RECOMPILE):

```
SELECT @TheirValue = X.carriervalue
        FROM dbo.Filteredcrossreference X
        WHERE
        X.carrier = @CarrierId
        and X.lookuptype = @LookupType
        and X.ourvalue = @OurValue
        and (@Parm4 IS NULL OR (X.parm4 = @Parm4))
                    and (@Parm5 IS NULL OR (X.parm5 = @Parm5))
                    and (@Parm6 IS NULL OR (X.parm6 = @Parm6))
```

```
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Can you show us the body of the UDF?

Comment: Can you share (part of) the code for the function `[dbo].[fn_GetXRef]`? Or explain what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Why are you hiding the important part of the function, and only showing us the parameter list? We are not great at mind-reading.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, without seeing the body of your function.  But a common place to look will be at what parms are *actually passed*.  Chances are, you may think you're passing null, when actually you're passing an empty string, or a default value, or something along those lines.